# site is redirecting to old url

Tags: redirect, development, admin-panel

I have created a test store to test theme and plugins at and this test store is reside same directory where my live website is present my live website url is  and test store url is https://test.royalcandycompany.com/ all going well untill i open backend but after login it will redirect to the admin panel of my live website https://www.royalcandycompany.com/index.php/admin/dashboard/ to solve this problem i have changed the base url in core config table of database but it is still redirecting to same url. so please any one help me in this problem

Comment: It looks like you solved it, you might like to say how.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to change URL for store as well. 
In `core_config_data` table search for `path like '%base_url%'` update your URL accordingly for `unsecure` and `secure` in all entries and refresh cache.

Comment: the two keys are `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`. The cache also needs flushing after you update the DB like that

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i have already do this thing but noting happens

Comment: sometimes there are more than two entries due to different scope.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered there is more than one base_url definition in the core_config_data table.

If you run:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%'
```

You should see all of the definitions.
The scope was different on this definition and was overriding the default which I had already changed.

Answer (score 0):

I just renamed the publich_html/var/cache ( Cache folder) and it solved for me. The website started working for me .

Here are the details of fixes.

1. Changed the base URL in core_config_data with new URL
2. Renamed the Cache folder under public_html(magento root directory)/var/cache to random cach222
3. Reopened in an URL and it started working.

write me on bigbangthings@gmail.com in case of any issues.